# Subgroups of Quotient Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

Quick Question:

If $H \unlhd G$, then I know that the subgroups of $G/H$ are of the form $K/H$ where $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $H$.

If you have a subgroup $A$ of $G$ and $A$ does not contain $N$, is the convention that $A/N$ is the trivial group or is this group not even defined (I would imagine the latter, but just want to make sure as I have not seen this anywhere)?

Comment: $A/N$ is meaningless if $A$ does not contain $N$, but $AN/N$ is meaningful and often useful, as it is the image of $A$ under the canonical homomorphism $G \to G/N$, $g \mapsto gN$.

Comment: @Bungo Understood, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then $A/N$ is not even defined.

Comment: Thank you for your response.